# Running out of connections when TransferMode = Streamed

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a simple REST service, and am calling it with WCF via `WebChannelFactory`.
When I set the binding to use `TransferMode.Streamed`, the connections do not seem to be re-used, and after several requests (usually `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit`, but sometimes a few more), I run out of connections (the request call hangs, and then I get a Timeout exception).

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IInviteAPI {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "invites/{id}", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        Invite GetInvite(string id);
    }

    [STAThread]
    static int Main(string[] args) {
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 16; // make a larger default
        WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding();
        binding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed;

        try {
            WebChannelFactory<IInviteAPI> factory = new WebChannelFactory<IInviteAPI>(binding, new Uri("http://example.com/invite"));
            IInviteAPI channel = factory.CreateChannel();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                Invite data = channel.GetInvite("160");  // fails on i==16
            }
            ((IChannel)channel).Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

`System.TimeoutException: The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:00:59.9969999.`

There are many many posts on the net about not closing the channel - **this is not the problem here**, as I am simply making the same request multiple times on the same channel.

- If I remove the `binding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed;` line it works perfectly.
- I can also create and close the channel inside the loop, and it has the same issue

  ```
          for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
              IInviteAPI channel = factory.CreateChannel();
              Invite data = channel.GetInvite("160");  // fails on i==20
              ((IChannel)channel).Close();
          }
  ```
- Interestingly, if I add a `GC.Collect()` in the loop, it does work!!  After much detailed tracing through the .Net code, this seems to be because the `ServicePoint` is only held with a weak reference in the `ServicePointManager`. Calling `GC.Collect` then finalizes the `ServicePoint`, and closes all the current connections.

Is there something I am missing? How can I keep `TransferMode.Streamed` and be able to call the service multiple times, with a reasonable `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit`?

(I need `TransferMode.Streamed` because other calls on the service are for transferring huge archives of data up to 1GB)

**Update**:
If I run netstat -nb I can see that there are 16 connections to the server in ESTABLISHED state.  After 30 seconds or so, they change to CLOSE_WAIT (presumably the server closes the idle connection), but these CLOSE_WAIT connections never disappear after that, no matter how big I set the timeouts.

It seems like a bug in .Net: the connections should be being re-used, but are not. The 17th request is just being queued forever.

Comment: When calling a streamed WCF service with a WCF client, the connection is not closed until you dispose the response stream. Closing the proxy does not close the connection.

Comment: In your case you seem to be deserializing the response to an Invite object in memory. I guess that means you don't need TransferMode.Streamed, or you should find another approach.

Comment: There are only specific circumstances where streaming with WCF will work. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742(v=vs.110).aspx Take a look at the MessageContract. The only body member should be a stream. If you can't do that, take a look at HttpClient.

Comment: Thanks @JssDWt, yes I have other methods that take a Stream parameter to send large chunks of data. 
According to the docs:
* **Transport-level streaming also works with any other message contract type** (parameter lists, data contract arguments, and explicit message contract), but because the serialization and deserialization of such typed messages requires buffering by the serializer, using such contract variants is not advisable.*

Comment: So I would expect the calls above to "work".  In my case above, it is the WCF proxy that should be managing closing of the response stream from reading the Invite object.  (I don't expect the connection to actually close, I expect it to be reused for the next request i.e. HTTP pipelining)

Answer (score 0):

I know that there is a 20 limit of concurrent inbound connections to the WCF configuration default limits, concurrency and scalability.

you can incrase concurrent connection limit or :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
     Invite data = channel.GetInvite("160");
     Thread.Sleep(1000); // prevent to concurrency connection to wcf service
}
```

Comment: The problem is not concurrent connections. All the requests are being performed in series - only one connection should be needed.

Comment: Also, the server is not a WCF service, it is a Java based REST service, and has no concurrency limits. The limit is purely on the client side.